# using try/catch method to get a parameter that will make a certain output from a method in java

Tags: java

I wrote this code using try/catch, and I want it to output this:

```
A null pointer exception occurred
In the finally block

The length of the string is 1
A number format exception occurred
In the finally block

A null pointer exception occurred
Some type of exception occurred
In the finally block

The length of the string is 1
The value is 5
```

but for some reason when I call I try to call it from the main I get an error, so my question is how can I properly call the method from the main to get the output above?

this is the method I wrote:

```
public static void problem2(String s) {
    try {
        int stringLen = s.length();
        System.out.println("The length of the string is " + stringLen);
        int i = Integer.parseInt(s);
        System.out.println("The value is " + i);
    } catch (NumberFormatException e1) {
        System.out.println("A number format exception occurred");
    } catch (NullPointerException e2) {
        System.out.println("A null pointer exception occurred");
    } catch (Exception e3) {
        System.out.println("Some type of exception occurred");
    } finally {
        System.out.println("In the finally block");
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the error that you get?

Comment: I have just test it and it works, so as Kevin says what is the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you placed this static method in a class "TryCatchExample", then the following will produce the output for examples 1, 2, and 4. Since you caught the NullPointerException, the code will not pass from one catch block to the next. Furthermore, why would you want to? You caught the more specific Exception, which might allow some specific feedback to the user. The more general Exception is less informative, and is considered by many to be a bad approach.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    TryCatchExample.problem2(null);  // prints NPE
    TryCatchExample.problem2("A"); // prints numberformat
    // no example for both numberformat and npe
    TryCatchExample.problem2("5"); // prints lengths & value 5
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've just run your code and it seems to run fine

```
public class UnknownError {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    problem2("hello");

}

 public static void problem2(String s) {

      try {
      int stringLen = s.length();
      System.out.println("The length of the string is " + stringLen);
      int i = Integer.parseInt(s);
      System.out.println("The value is " + i);

      } catch (NumberFormatException e1) {
      System.out.println("A number format exception occurred");

      } catch (NullPointerException e2) {
      System.out.println("A null pointer exception occurred");

      } catch (Exception e3) {
      System.out.println("Some type of exception occurred");

      } finally {
      System.out.println("In the finally block");
        }
 }
```

}

Are you calling the method differently to this?

Answer (score 0):

The method has the below signature and has three possibilities. I would like you to understand the below possibilities and then call your method with appropriate parameter's values or make changes in your code to get the output you wish. It will be better learning for you rather than I putting down the solution code or you.

`public static void problem2(String s)`

**1st Possibility**

If the parameter s is Null then `int stringLen = s.length();` will cause `NullPointerException` as you are trying to fetch length() from an object that was never created (null). So now code flow will reach the below block.

```
catch (NullPointerException e2) {
  System.out.println("A null pointer exception occurred");

  }
```

So next Line printed is **A null pointer exception occurred**

Next finally will be called and next line printed will be **In the finally block**

**2nd Possibility**

In case the parameter is not null.

```
int stringLen = s.length();
System.out.println("The length of the string is " + stringLen);
```

Above code will print **The length of the string is 1** (1 if only one character is present in the string).

In case s contains a string which does not corresponds to an `Integer` in that case

```
int i = Integer.parseInt(s);
```

This code will will throw `NumberFormatException` and flow will reach below code.

```
catch (NumberFormatException e1) {
  System.out.println("A number format exception occurred");
}
```

This will print **A number format exception occurred**

Again finally block will be executed and **In the finally block** will be printed.

**3rd Possibility**

In case your String parameter is not null and contains a Character corresponding to a valid Integer then

```
int stringLen = s.length();
System.out.println("The length of the string is " + stringLen);
int i = Integer.parseInt(s);
System.out.println("The value is " + i);
```

this code will result in printing **The length of the string is ** followed by **The value is 1** followed by the string printed from the finally block, **In the finally block**.